# Outlook Add-in REST API - unable to send a mail from a shared mailbox

Tags: api, rest, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

Good morning,
I have a big problem on Outlook Addin when trying to send an email from a shared mailbox. I'm using the outlook v2 REST API and the message I get is: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
I can create a forward, I can update the draft of the forward but cannot send it!
What is blocking the sending?
Any help is welcome

Thanks in advance.

I tried everything possible

Comment: What code have you tries so far? Do you develop an Outlook web add-in or VSTO one?